# If I hit the daily rep cap and then get downvoted, does it still count towards badges?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, down-votes, daily-reputation-limit

Say I hit the daily rep cap (with a great overhead, say 40 upvotes for answers, which would translate to 400 rep) and THEN get one downvote, then the day ends. At the end of the day I gained +198 rep. Does it still count that I hit the daily rep cap that day? For example, will I get [the Mortarboard badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/mortarboard), and will I make progress on [Epic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/epic) and [Legendary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many years ago, we simplified the logic for the daily reputation badges.

**They only consider positive reputation changes.** That means the script that awards the badge doesn't even *look* at downvotes, and in that regard doesn't actually pay attention to how much net reputation you earned at all. It only adds up the total reputation you gained from upvotes, accepts, bounties, and suggested edits to see if that amount is >= 200. It's even possible for a day to count if you received a series of downvotes early on but still accumulated 200 reputation after that and *never even hit the reputation cap*. As long as you *earned* 200 that day.

Note however, that the live badge progress works slightly differently. It just looks at the current net amount (including negative events) while you're on the current day, but *will* eventually count the day later on when it rechecks your account if downvotes caused it to drop below 200.

Answer (score 20):

I don't know whether it "counts" for badge and rep report purposes... but you *will* lose the 2 rep. Of course, it only takes one upvote to get you back on track, even if you've had up to 5 downvotes. But it sucks for the last vote of the day to be a downvote...

Comment: Thanks for stating that is sucks, 'cuz it really does, but I am actually keeping track of the number of days I have hit the daily rep cap and need to know whether it counts or not :)

Comment: How would _you_ ever know what it is to _just_ hit 200 and be downvoted? ;)

Comment: @yoda: What he's saying is that even if you're way past the cap, and a bunch of upvotes have all given you +0 rep, a downvote will *still* give you -2 rep, which you'll only recoup if you get another upvote *later* in the same day.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan The rule for Legendary is "at least 200 rep", so one accept saves you the troubles, because then you have 213 :-)

Answer (score 11):

It happened to me today, and I can say that **previously capped points don't come back.**

[image: reputation overview]

<del>I had enough to get Mortarboard, but now I won't because the last one was a downvote. I started a rep recalculation, and that changed nothing :/ Note that although it shows 273, it still only counts as 198 because Mortarboard [is for upvotes only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59686/what-is-a-mortarboard/68256#68256).</del>

See the second screenshot after I got another upvote:

[image: reputation overview 2]

Comment: incorrect, accepted answers count now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258

Comment: Why is there no "official" documentation about that - all is in meta questions and answers that are partly outdated :/

Comment: The badge description is "Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day". It was recently updated (within a couple months ago, I believe) to say this so that it's clearer that it has nothing to actually do with the reputation cap.

Answer (score 5):

If this happened to you, *you* can actually tell *us* if it counts!

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation (or `http://(sitename)/reputation`) to audit your reputation. At the very bottom of the page, it shows how many times you've hit the rep cap. Correlate those numbers based on the daily history and see if the day in question is or isn't included. Please let us know the result!

Comment: It definitely matters when you got a cap and then downvoted and no upvotes for the day. Really sucks. That lost rep should come back.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question highlighted by @doppelgreener's bounty: yes, it counts towards those badges. Those badges [only count positive reputation events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/295232), so even if you get 10 upvotes on an answer, one downvote and then another 10 upvotes, you'll qualify for the Mortarboard badge and one part of the Epic/Legendary badges.

> Down votes cast or received do not count towards this badge. ([source 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181103), [source 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100512/why-dont-i-have-the-mortarboard-badge))

Comment: I've added mention of those badges to the question proper, so now it's not just highlighted by the bounty.

Comment: Nope, sorry, this is wrong (speaking from experience). cc @doppelgreener

Comment: I'm sorry @Randal'Thor but you're wrong (also speaking from experience *and* the FAQ which I forgot to link).

Comment: @Glorfindel I guess those old posts from 2011 and 2013 are out of date (possibly from the days of "manual recalc" which I missed?) Because +2/+15 from accepts does count IME, [in contrast to this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100572/278659).

Comment: Yes, those count; according to my own experience, all positive rep actions count.

Answer (score 5):

**If you hit the rep cap and then get downvoted, it does NOT count for progress towards Epic / Legendary.** But your Mortarboard badge won't be revoked if it's your first time hitting the repcap and you already earned it that day.

Source: I remember getting a downvote just before midnight on one of my high-rep sites which sent my daily rep down to 198 and decremented my count on Epic/Legendary back down to 1 less than it had been before that downvote.

Comment: This is not how it works. That's just an oversimplification of the badge progress tracker for performance purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what happened to me yesterday / today - and as Jon said, "it sucks for the last vote of the day to be a downvote" (at this point, with that particular answer standing at +70/-3, it sucks a lot).

This is the tail end of my `/reputation` report:

```
 2    240635 [0]
 2    240635 [0]
 2    240635 [0]
 2    240635 [0]
 2    240635 [0]
 3    240635 [-2]
-- 2014-10-08 rep +198  = 1046      
 2    240635 (10)
-- 2014-10-09 rep +10   = 1056      

** rep today: 10
** rep this week (2014-10-05 - 2014-10-11): 408
** rep this month (2014-10-01 - 2014-10-31): 408
** rep this quarter (2014-10-01 - 2014-12-31): 408
** rep this year (2014-01-01 - 2014-12-31): 498
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 1056 :)

days represented 29
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 2 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 1 days
earned 0 reputation from suggested edits
```

As you can see, I ended up with 198 points for the day although I had many "uncounted" upvotes; but "rep cap was reached" counter does stand at 2, meaning that hitting the rep cap *at some point in the day* appears to have been enough to trigger that count (although by the end of the day I had 198 points).

It's unlikely I'll ever get to 50 days of repcap on meta - but it does make me wonder whether my counter stands at 1 ("earned at least 200 reputation on 1 days") or 2 ("rep cap was reached...") at this point.

So yes - this suggests that the last downvote can take away points that don't get restored; it does leave me wondering what happens to the rep cap counter, as the above is ambiguous.

Comment: The badge counters dont go backwards. But then, yes, that thing with "order matters" is somehow unfair....