# Why don't I have the 'Mortarboard' badge?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges, daily-reputation-badges

On the 28th July I got 201 rep:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/370103/curt?tab=reputation

Therefore, shouldn't I have the Mortarboard badge?

Comment: If you don't get a definitive answer soon, try looking at your [reputation audit](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and look at the very last line to see the count of days you received 200 reputation.  It should read (at least) `1`.  Maybe even recalc?  It might be possible that an upvoted post was deleted and somehow got out of sync.

Comment: We're looking at this, I see why you haven't gotten it (+2 from accepts don't count)...but I'm not sure if this is intentional.  I'll get back to you on this, and explain/fix today.

Comment: Nice find @Nick if by design we'll have to edit that part in the faq: "Reputation source can be any vote type, upvotes, accepted answers, bounties...any net increase from votes (not association) totaling >= 200."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We've decided to leave the badge as-is for the moment (it's been this way for as long as it's existed, as far as I can tell).

In short: **+2 rep from accepts don't count**, so you can't game the system up to 200+ rep by saving up your accept votes just for the badge.

Comment: in that case can the faq be updated:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258  It states specifically that accepts are included.

Comment: @jzd - refresh, the community has already done that (you guys never cease to amaze) :)

Answer (score 6):

You should have it for the reputation you gained on July 28. As reported [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258), part of the FAQ:

> Reputation source can be any vote type, upvotes, accepted answers, bounties...any net increase from votes (not association) totaling >= 200.

Looking at a previous revision of that answer, you can notice that the text used before was the following, which means that bounties were not counted, but they are counted now.

> Exceeding the cap is defined as earning ≥200 reputation in one day from a combination of upvotes and accepts, but not bounties

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Bounties don't count toward the 200 rep requirement.  And without the two bounties you received you are well under 200.</strike>

It would appear bounties do count:

[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Therefore: it looks like you meet the full requirements.  Normally I would say wait a little longer before you worry, but it has been a couple days which should have given the process enough time to run.  The last person to earn the badge was from rep on July 30th.

Comment: So shouldnt I have the badge?

Comment: @Curt, yes I believe you should.