# Rep cap bug on MSO

Tags: bug, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What if I hit the daily rep cap and THEN get downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70158/what-if-i-hit-the-daily-rep-cap-and-then-get-downvoted)

This is [my rep page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178438/tim-manishearth?tab=reputation)(sorted by post) for May 10:
[image]

Sorted by time:

[image]

As you can see, on May 10, I hit the cap. But, I still have 198 instead of 200 rep for the day. I remember that the day rep was at 200 for me pretty much the whole day, and then later it came down to 198 without one of the above-cap-rep recomplensating for it.

I want my Epic badge! ;-)

Looks like a bug..

P.S.: [image]

Also, I ran a recalc already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get recompensated for downvotes if the upvote occurs ***after*** the downvote occurred. If you get a downvote after hitting the reputation cap, you still lose the 2 reputation, which can then be gained back with another upvote that day.

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the [rep faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) ?

Comment: It probably should be. It follows the same premise as the "you can't be downvoted below 1 reputation" thing. Get a bunch of downvotes at 1, then get an upvote, the downvotes still don't count. :)