# Does a downvote after reaching the daily rep cap cause rep to decrease inline with excess upvotes?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What if I hit the daily rep cap and THEN get downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70158/what-if-i-hit-the-daily-rep-cap-and-then-get-downvoted)

The title pretty much states it all.  If you have reached your daily cap, and have excess upvotes that would have otherwise increased rep, does downvoting take into account the excess upvotes before decreasing rep or does downvoting decrease rep directly?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132460/rep-cap-bug-on-mso for an example of what happens

Comment: It would be hard to match the wording.  Thanks for pointing out the dup.

Comment: @hydroparadise: The algorithms for related questions (at the right) is surprisingly good at finding duplicates. Much better than the algorithm on the *Ask Question* page, sadly...

Answer (score 2):

If you get downvoted after reaching the rep cap, the downvote still counts.

However, if you get upvoted again afterwards, the next upvote will be worth `+2` points, cancelling the previous downvote.