# Do the order in which upvotes/Downvotes given in a day also matter towards rep limit?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What if I hit the daily rep cap and THEN get downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70158/what-if-i-hit-the-daily-rep-cap-and-then-get-downvoted)

I know about the 200 reputation per day system from upvotes/downvotes (both given or received).

I also know that bounty, association bonus and answers (both accepting answer to your question and others accepting your answers) do not count towards this limit.

I have also read about this [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

**But do the order in which upvotes/Downvotes given in a day also matter towards rep limit?**

I will show you a pic of my reps for [15th May 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011959/nikhil-agrawal?tab=reputation)  to explain better.

[image]

Events for the day in order of happeneing

1. I hit 200 limit for a day. (that's why got +14(from 2 upvotes) where i should have got 20. No problem. +6 gone.)
2. Then someone downvotes my 1 answer(-2). It get added to my rep. So my rep limit becomes 200 - 2 = 198.

Now do the reputation cover up for the nagative reputation (-2) received for the day from those +6 which were not given to me.

In simpler words will i get +2 from that +6 which i did not get?

(I did reputation audit today but still the same.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reputation from votes is assigned in the order the votes were given.

So if you hit the rep cap and then get a down-vote you will need *another* up-vote to get the +2 "back" to take you to 200 points for the day again.

However, don't worry about it.

Comment: I *think* this might be different after the latest round of rep changes, but don't quote me on that. Gonna have to for-science (or, y'know, ask :)).

Comment: +1 for "*However, don't worry about it.*"