# Why my rep cap will not consider negative reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What if I hit the daily rep cap and THEN get downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70158/what-if-i-hit-the-daily-rep-cap-and-then-get-downvoted)

Once my reputation reaches 200 (without accepts), even though I have multiple upvotes, any negative reputation change will not compensate from existing 0 reputation upvotes.

How is it justified ?

Comment: Should it be justified? Things happen one after the other - that's the nature of events.

Comment: yes , but in [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70158/what-if-i-hit-the-daily-rep-cap-and-then-get-downvoted) no justification provided

Comment: @TechExchange: That's why Manishearth made it a `related / *possible* dupe` comment. I won't vote on this as a dupe.

Comment: That said, yes it sucks, but I am not yet convinced that allowing capped votes (so +0) to compensate for a final downvote before the end of the day is going to be fair either.

Comment: It is a rare enough occurrence that I don't see a need for compensating action, considering it is only 1% at most of the total rep gained that day.

Comment: it happens to me more often, say i have 300 rep( +100 because of accepted answers). then suddenly one question is removed / downvote and end of day i remain with say 290 even though after 300 i'd have got 5 or 6 upvotes

Comment: @TechExchange: Question removed is an entirely different matter. If a question is removed, then your rep is recalculated as if the question never existed in the first place. (so the rep gets recalced for the days you got votes on that question, not the day of deletion)

Comment: {shrug} Why don't people who continually ask terrible questions or provide terrible answers and get downvoted accordingly ever have their reputation go below 1?